# clause with "where"

Tags: grammar, where

Here is the question sentence: I've got a slim friend from London where is the financial center of the UK.

I just feel confused about the word "where". 
Is it right? 
Or should I change it for "which".

Many thanks.

Comment: Use *which*....

Answer (score 1):

*Which* is better (describing London as the financial centre of the UK).

If you want to consider the [City of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_London) district as being the actual financial centre, it would be possible to say *London, where the financial centre of the UK is*.